# Не могу сохранить массив в текст

Tags: java

В кнопке numx.write Пишет : "The method write(int) in the type BufferedWriter is not applicable for the arguments (List)"
A если ввожу numx.write(Arrays.asList(x); То вывод ошибку : "Type mismatch: cannot convert from List to int" Как сохранить в виде массива в тексте, чтобы потом обращаться к каждому элементу из текста?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


    public class Start extends JFrame {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -6516165981432576014L;
        //Local variables
    private JTextField m[] = new JTextField[9];     
    private String n[] = new String[9];    
    private int x[] = new int [9];  
    private JButton button;

    Start(){
            //Top
            super("Determinant");
            //Closing
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
            //Label
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("detA.png"));
            //ArrayList
            Box box1 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            Box box2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            Box box3 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            for (int i = 0; i<9; i++) {
            m[i] = new JTextField(1);
            //First Line
            if  (i < 3) {        
                box1.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(1)); 
                box1.add(m[i]);     
            }
            //Second Line
            else if ((i>=3) && (i<6)){               
                box2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(1)); 
                box2.add(m[i]);
            }
            else  if (i>=6) {
            //Third Line    
                box3.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(1));
                box3.add(m[i]);
            }
            }
            //Make Button
            button = new JButton("Result");
            Box box4 = Box.createHorizontalBox();   
            box4.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
            box4.add(button);

            for (int i = 0;i<9;i++)   {   
                try {
                n[i] = m[i].getText();                       
             x[i] = Integer.parseInt(n[i]);}
                     catch (NumberFormatException e) {                       
                     } ;
            }               
            //buttonListener        
                 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                   
                         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {                                                       
                             try {                                               
                                    FileWriter saveX = new FileWriter("test.txt", true);
                                    BufferedWriter numx = new BufferedWriter(saveX);                                
                                    List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(x);

                                    numx.write(list);
                                    numx.close();
                                  } 
                             catch (Exception e) {                               
                             }                           
                             }                   
                 });                                
            //Make MainBox
            Box mainBox = Box.createVerticalBox();
            mainBox.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(12,12,12,12));
            setContentPane(mainBox);
            mainBox.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(10));
            getContentPane().add(label);            
            mainBox.add(box1);
            mainBox.add(box2);
            mainBox.add(box3);
            mainBox.add(box4);

            //Size and visible
            pack();
            setResizable(false);
            setVisible(true);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try (BufferedWriter numx = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test.txt", true))){
    numx.write(Arrays.toString(x));
} catch (Exception e) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Он сохраняет теперь массив, но все элементы нули. Похоже он не может забрать значения(текст), а выдаёт просто индекс

Comment: Ну а что же оно еще должно писать, если Вы заполняете массив x раньше, чем ввели значения в поля? Цикл, который заполняет массив х вставьте в обработчик события кнопки, перед самой записью в файл и будет Вам счастье.